# Remove text between a semicolon and a quotation mark in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I want to remove text between the second semicolon and the last quotation mark of the line.
This is what I currently got :

```
"number1;text1;text2;text3"
```

The problem is that I got many lines (more than one hundred) like the previous one in my file and the text is always different. For example, another line could be :

```
"number2;text4;text5;text6"
```

I would like to apply a specific method in the replace bar (Ctrl + H) to solve my problem.

This is what I want :

```
"number1;text1" for the first line
"number2;text4" for the second line
```

Comment: use the search and replace function of notepad together with an regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^;]+;[^;]+\K[^"]+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  [^;]+     # 1 or more non semicolon
  ;         # 1 semicolon
  [^;]+     # 1 or more non semicolon
  \K        # forget all we have seen until this position
  [^"]+     # 1 or more non double quote
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]